# Amazon S3 returns "SignatureDoesNotMatch" on download using mono

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, mono, .net-4.5, ubuntu-14.04

I am downloading files from S3 using this code

```
   protected void FileDownload(FileInfo localFile)
    {
        using (AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(this.accessKey, this.secretKey, this.regionEndpoint))
        {
            using (GetObjectResponse response = s3Client.GetObject(this.bucketName, this.key))
            {
                response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(localFile.FullName);
            }
        }
    }
```

From windows everything works, but when using mono on ubuntu then S3 responds with a http-403 saying "SignatureDoesNotMatch". Any idee?

I am using ubuntu-14.04, mono 3.12.1, .net4.5 and AWSSDK 2.3.24.1